# Mysql Server within docker instance, LOAD_FILE returning NULL

Tags: mysql, docker

I've tried all day at this -

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE("/var/lib/mysql-files/CustomerImage.jpeg")
```

returns NULL even though the file exists there.  I've checked the secure-file-priv setting, the permissions are set to ALL on ROOT.  The file has execute permissions.  I've restarted the server so the permissions are definitely flushed.  The File permission is granted.  I don't know what I'm missing.  This is within a docker instance so I don't know if there's anything to add to this as a result.

Comment: place the file in `/tmp` inside the container and see if it works?

Comment: tried that.  We've gone with a different solution.

Comment: do post that solution as answer